# Faceted Range Query for Solr. Can't parse gap 1,2,3,10 for field

Tags: solr, solr4, solr-query-syntax

I am trying to query data (using solr) and get castleid granularity.

I have a local running instance of **Solr 4.10**.

On a begging I've made simple query like in solr wiki for range faceting:
[Solr examples for range faceting](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#rangefaceting)

I tried the following query:

```
&facet=true
&facet.range=castleid
&f.castleid.facet.range.start=0
&f.castleid.facet.range.end=1000
&f.castleid.facet.range.gap=1,2,3,10
```

url for this query:

```
select?q=table%3Acontent&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.range=castleid&f.castleid.facet.range.start=0&f.castleid.facet.range.end=10000&facet.range.gap=1%2C2%2C3%2C10
```

The error I am getting is:

*"Can't parse gap 1,2,3,10 for field: castleid"*

**Am I doing something wrong or it is impossible to make ranges this way?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example refers to a experimental feature that, as far as I can see, [is not committed in the current version](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2366).

You might be able to solve it by using [Interval Faceting](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-IntervalFaceting) instead (although that will require you to create the interval buckets yourself).

Answer (score 2):

Full answer for my example is:

*I enabled interval by setting docValues=“true” in the schema for castleid field.
And corresponding query should look like:*

```
&facet=true
&facet.interval=castleid
&f.castleid.facet.interval.set=[0,1]
&f.castleid.facet.interval.set=[2,2]
&f.castleid.facet.interval.set=[3,3]
&f.castleid.facet.interval.set=[4,13]
&f.castleid.facet.interval.set=[14,23]
&f.castleid.facet.interval.set=[24,33] 
. 
. 
.
&f.castleid.facet.interval.set=[994,1003]
```